# Laravel 8: How to execute Artisan command in controller with docker command?

Tags: docker, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I need to run an artisan command on the server but with docker exec command from the controller? I'm not sure if this is the right way

```
Artisan::call('docker exec -u1000 {CONTAINER_NAME} php artisan doSomething');
```

Is the final command to be like this: `php artisan docker exec -u1000 {CONTAINER_NAME} php artisan doSomething` or will be correct like this `docker exec -u1000 {CONTAINER_NAME} php artisan doSomething`

Comment: Isn't `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call("doSomething");` sufficient?

Comment: yes but I need to add `docker exec -u1000 {CONTAINER_NAME}` before `php artisan` what's the correct command if mine is wrong?